# Puppeteer: abort requests inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, puppeteer

I need to abort images and media/video requests inside iframes using Puppeteer.
This is not for a specific iframe I need to abort the requests in every iframe.

The purpose of this is to remove adult content in some ads found inside iframes on mostly adult websites such as redtube.com and pornhub.com and then display the resulting screenshot.

This is what I need to do inside iframes:

```js
  if (request.resourceType() == 'media' ||
      url.indexOf('.mp4') !== -1 ||
      url.indexOf('.avi') !== -1 ||
      url.indexOf('.flv') !== -1 ||
      url.indexOf('.mov') !== -1 ||
      url.indexOf('.wmv') !== -1) {
             request.abort();
   }

  if (request.resourceType() == 'image' && url.indexOf('.png') === -1 && url.indexOf('.svg') === -1 {
     request.abort();
  }
```

So, the question is how can I abort image and media requests inside all iframes?

Answer (score 0):

This might work, each `request` has an associated `frame` property which you can get by [request.frame()](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-class-request). There is also [page.mainFrame()](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-pagemainframe). You can abort the request if you can successfully tell `request.frame != page.mainFrame`. One way would be to compare the `frame.url()` with `page.url()`.

Comment: @turrican_34, `request.frame().url() !== page.mainFrame().url()`.